# Install step for SharePoint 2013 fails on my Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: error, prerequisites

I am in Kathmandu Nepal trying to setup a SharePoint server and can't get past the prerequisite step.

I am pretty sure I have the pre-reqs; log file and error message appended below. But hell, not thinking straight with all these aftershocks :) My guess is the error has to with

> "The tool was unable to install Application Server Role, Web Server (IIS) Role."

That one baffles me, as the web server seems just fine. Can anyone provide some clues, pointers, etc. I've already tried so many things by googling stuff and downloading scripts that are supposed to fix this. Thx!

Here is the log:

[image]

```
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - Processor architecture is (9)
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - Reading the following string value/name...
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - Common Startup
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - from the following registry location...
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - The value is... 
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - Trying to remove the startup task if there is any.
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\SharePointServerPreparationToolStartup_0FF1CE14-0000-0000-0000-000000000000.cmd
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - Error: Startup task doesn't exist. This is not a continuation after a restart.
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - Locating the following command line arguments file:
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - \\psf\Home\Downloads\Sharepoint Installer\PrerequisiteInstaller.Arguments.txt
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - Error: This file does not exist
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - Details of the current operating system: 
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - Major version number of the operating system:  (6)
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - Minor version number of the operating system:  (2)
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - Build number of the operating system:  (0X23F0=9200)
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - Major version number of the latest Service Pack:  (0)
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - Minor version number of the latest Service Pack:  (0)
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - Platform ID of the operating system:  (2)
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - Product suites available on the operating system:  (0X190=400)
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - Product type of the operating system: VER_NT_DOMAIN_CONROLLER
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - Product type:  (8)
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - OS type:  (0)
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - Configuring the application's property sheet...
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - Check whether the following prerequisite is installed:
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - Windows Management Framework 3.0
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - Reading the following string value/name...
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - PowerShellVersion
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - from the following registry location...
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\3\PowerShellEngine
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - The value is... 
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - 4.0
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - A higher version of the prerequisite above is already installed
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - Check whether the following prerequisite is installed:
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - Reading the following DWORD value/name...
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - Install
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - from the following registry location...
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\V4\full
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - The value is (1)
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - Reading the following string value/name...
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - Version
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - from the following registry location...
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\V4\full
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - The value is... 
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - 4.6.00057
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - A post release .NET 4.5 is installed
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - Check whether the following prerequisite is installed:
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - Windows Identity Foundation (KB974405)
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - Reading the following string value/name...
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - 
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - from the following registry location...
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Identity Foundation\Setup\v3.5
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - The value is... 
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - 6.1.7600.0
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - The prerequisite above is already installed
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - Check whether the following prerequisite is installed:
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - Microsoft Sync Framework Runtime v1.0 SP1 (x64)
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - Reading version of the following file...
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Synchronization\1.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.Synchronization.dll
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - The version is...
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - 1.0.3010.0
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - The prerequisite above is already installed
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - Check whether the following prerequisite is installed:
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1 Native Client
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - Reading the following string value/name...
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - Version
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - from the following registry location...
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\SQLNCLI10\CurrentVersion
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - The value is... 
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - 10.51.2500.0
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - A higher version of the prerequisite above is already installed
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - Check whether the following prerequisite is installed:
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - Windows Server AppFabric
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - Reading the following string value/name...
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - ProductVersion
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - from the following registry location...
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - SOFTWARE\Microsoft\AppFabric\V1.0
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - The value is... 
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - 1.1.2106.32
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - Reading the following string value/name...
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - ProductVersion
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - from the following registry location...
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - SOFTWARE\Microsoft\AppFabric\V1.0
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - The value is... 
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - 1.1.2106.32
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - Reading the following string value/name...
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - ProductVersion
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - from the following registry location...
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - SOFTWARE\Microsoft\AppFabric\V1.0
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - The value is... 
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - 1.1.2106.32
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - Reading the following DWORD value/name...
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - DCC
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - from the following registry location...
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - SOFTWARE\Microsoft\AppFabric\V1.0\Features
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - Check whether the following prerequisite is installed:
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - Windows Identity Foundation (KB974405)
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - Reading the following string value/name...
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - 
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - from the following registry location...
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft Identity Extensions\Setup\1.0
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - The value is... 
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - 2.0.1459.0
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - A higher version of the prerequisite above is already installed
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - Check whether the following prerequisite is installed:
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - Microsoft Information Protection and Control Client
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - Reading the following string value/name...
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - 
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - from the following registry location...
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSIPC\CurrentVersion
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - The value is... 
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - 1.0.621.117
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - A higher version of the prerequisite above is already installed
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - Check whether the following prerequisite is installed:
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - Microsoft WCF Data Services 5.0
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - Reading the following string value/name...
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - Version
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - from the following registry location...
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft WCF Data Services\5.0
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - The value is... 
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - 5.0.51212.0
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - A higher version of the prerequisite above is already installed
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - Check whether the following prerequisite is installed:
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - Cumulative Update Package 1 for Microsoft AppFabric 1.1 for Windows Server (KB2671763)
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - Reading the following DWORD value/name...
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - IsInstalled
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - from the following registry location...
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Updates\AppFabric 1.1 for Windows Server\KB2671763
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - The value is (1)
2015-05-18 10:34:41 - The prerequisite above is already installed
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - Beginning download/installation
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - Created thread for installer
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - "C:\Windows\system32\ServerManagerCmd.exe" -inputpath "C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\Pre1026.tmp.XML"
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - Error: Unable to install (2)
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - Error: [In HRESULT format] (-2147024894)
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - Last return code (2)
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - Reading the following DWORD value/name...
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - Flags
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - from the following registry location...
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Updates\UpdateExeVolatile
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - Reading the following string value/name...
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - PendingFileRenameOperations
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - from the following registry location...
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - Reading the following registry location...
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\Auto Update\RebootRequired
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - Error: The tool was unable to install Application Server Role, Web Server (IIS) Role.
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - Last return code (2)
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - Options for further diagnostics: 1. Look up the return code value 2. Download the prerequisite manually and verify size downloaded by the prerequisite installer. 3. Install the prerequisite manually from the given location without any command line options.
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - Cannot retry
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - Check whether the following prerequisite is installed:
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - Windows Management Framework 3.0
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - Reading the following string value/name...
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - PowerShellVersion
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - from the following registry location...
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\3\PowerShellEngine
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - The value is... 
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - 4.0
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - A higher version of the prerequisite above is already installed
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - Check whether the following prerequisite is installed:
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - Reading the following DWORD value/name...
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - Install
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - from the following registry location...
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\V4\full
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - The value is (1)
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - Reading the following string value/name...
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - Version
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - from the following registry location...
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\V4\full
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - The value is... 
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - 4.6.00057
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - A post release .NET 4.5 is installed
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - Check whether the following prerequisite is installed:
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - Windows Identity Foundation (KB974405)
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - Reading the following string value/name...
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - 
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - from the following registry location...
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Identity Foundation\Setup\v3.5
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - The value is... 
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - 6.1.7600.0
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - The prerequisite above is already installed
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - Check whether the following prerequisite is installed:
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - Microsoft Sync Framework Runtime v1.0 SP1 (x64)
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - Reading version of the following file...
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Synchronization\1.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.Synchronization.dll
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - The version is...
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - 1.0.3010.0
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - The prerequisite above is already installed
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - Check whether the following prerequisite is installed:
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1 Native Client
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - Reading the following string value/name...
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - Version
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - from the following registry location...
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\SQLNCLI10\CurrentVersion
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - The value is... 
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - 10.51.2500.0
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - A higher version of the prerequisite above is already installed
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - Check whether the following prerequisite is installed:
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - Windows Server AppFabric
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - Reading the following string value/name...
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - ProductVersion
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - from the following registry location...
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - SOFTWARE\Microsoft\AppFabric\V1.0
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - The value is... 
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - 1.1.2106.32
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - Reading the following string value/name...
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - ProductVersion
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - from the following registry location...
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - SOFTWARE\Microsoft\AppFabric\V1.0
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - The value is... 
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - 1.1.2106.32
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - Reading the following string value/name...
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - ProductVersion
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - from the following registry location...
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - SOFTWARE\Microsoft\AppFabric\V1.0
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - The value is... 
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - 1.1.2106.32
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - Reading the following DWORD value/name...
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - DCC
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - from the following registry location...
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - SOFTWARE\Microsoft\AppFabric\V1.0\Features
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - Check whether the following prerequisite is installed:
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - Windows Identity Foundation (KB974405)
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - Reading the following string value/name...
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - 
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - from the following registry location...
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft Identity Extensions\Setup\1.0
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - The value is... 
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - 2.0.1459.0
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - A higher version of the prerequisite above is already installed
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - Check whether the following prerequisite is installed:
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - Microsoft Information Protection and Control Client
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - Reading the following string value/name...
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - 
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - from the following registry location...
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSIPC\CurrentVersion
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - The value is... 
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - 1.0.621.117
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - A higher version of the prerequisite above is already installed
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - Check whether the following prerequisite is installed:
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - Microsoft WCF Data Services 5.0
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - Reading the following string value/name...
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - Version
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - from the following registry location...
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft WCF Data Services\5.0
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - The value is... 
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - 5.0.51212.0
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - A higher version of the prerequisite above is already installed
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - Check whether the following prerequisite is installed:
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - Cumulative Update Package 1 for Microsoft AppFabric 1.1 for Windows Server (KB2671763)
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - Reading the following DWORD value/name...
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - IsInstalled
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - from the following registry location...
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Updates\AppFabric 1.1 for Windows Server\KB2671763
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - The value is (1)
2015-05-18 10:34:45 - The prerequisite above is already installed
2015-05-18 10:34:48 - Opening log file
2015-05-18 10:34:48 - Opened action for user
2015-05-18 10:34:48 - C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\prerequisiteinstaller.2015.05.18-10.34.41.log
2015-05-18 10:45:43 - Opening log file
2015-05-18 10:45:43 - Opened action for user
2015-05-18 10:45:43 - C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\prerequisiteinstaller.2015.05.18-10.34.41.log
```

Comment: Are you installing SharePoint 2013 WITH Service Pack 1 or without?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure if this is recommended solution or not but
I guess the the installer is trying to run the executable `C:\Windows\System32\ServerManagerCMD.exe`

`2014-09-03 23:45:23 - "C:\Windows\system32\ServerManagerCmd.exe" -inputpath "somepath"`

Taking a look in the system32 directory, you'll see that in R2, ServerManagerCMD.exe doesn't exist!

Source: [Server 2012 R2 and SharePoint 2013: The tool was unable to install Application Server Role, Web Server (IIS) Role](http://www.someshinyobject.com/posts/server-2012-r2-and-sharepoint-2013-the-tool-was-unable-to-install-application-server-role-web)

and microsoft has also provided a kb for this [The Products Preparation Tool in SharePoint Server 2013 may not progress past "Configuring Application Server Role, Web Server (IIS) Role"](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2765260)

Comment: thx, that did the trick. I'd upvote the others as well (good links) but I don't have a good reputation yet :(

Comment: Glad it helped.:) please mark it as answer so that thread can be closed :)

Answer (score 1):

You can refer these links.. Sure you will get some solution for that error..

[SharePoint 2013 Installation and Configuration Issues](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fabdulwahab/archive/2013/08/29/sharepoint-2013-installation-and-configuration-issues.aspx)

[SharePoint 2013 Pre requisites install fail, Error: The tool was unable to install Application Server Role, Web Server (IIS) Role](https://sharelockpoint.wordpress.com/2013/09/09/sharepoint-2013-pre-requisites-install-fail-error-the-tool-was-unable-to-install-application-server-role-web-server-iis-role/)

[Installing SharePoint 2013 on Windows Server 2012 R2 Preview](http://www.avivroth.com/2013/07/09/installing-sharepoint-2013-on-windows-server-2012-r2-preview/)

[Server 2012 R2 and SharePoint 2013: The tool was unable to install Application Server Role, Web Server (IIS) Role](http://www.someshinyobject.com/posts/server-2012-r2-and-sharepoint-2013-the-tool-was-unable-to-install-application-server-role-web)

[Configuring Application Server Role, Web Server (IIS) Role](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2765260)