# Not able to install SharePoint 2013 pre requisites after uninstalled them

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, prerequisites

I was on course of adding one new WFE sever to an existing farm, Installing pre requisites and SharePoint sever 2013 everything **went well for the first attempt**, But while patching the server I done some mistake and forced to un install SharePoint Server 2013 from Windows server 2012 R2.
Sorry for the blooper with that I also manually uninstalled SharePoint server 2013 pre requisites via server control panel. :( Thought starting everything in fresh

Now Im in real trouble, **While installing SharePoint 2013 pre requisites for the second time** (Using power shell script) it showing as everything already installed and no action has taken, But I can see nothing installed in control panel and SharePoint 2013 installation getting fail as well.

Below entries was there in the log file for a thousand time.

*2021-01-17 08:49:15 - Request for install time of Application Server Role, Web Server (IIS) Role
2021-01-17 08:49:15 - Error: Failed when formatting time according to the system locale (0X57=87)*

Below is the final screen shot of SharePoint product preparation tool.
[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: Hi, Are you sure the web and application roles are already installed on your server? also check this old thread that may help you https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/143055/error-the-tool-was-unable-to-install-application-server-role-web-server-iis

Answer (score 1):

Error: The tool was unable to install Application Server Role, Web Server (IIS) Role.

**To solve the issue, you could set the Local Policy:**

- Run MMC.exe

[image]

- On the **File** tab, click "**Add/Remove Snap-in...**"

[image]

- Select **Group Policy Object Editor** and **ADD** it

[image]

- Navigate to **Administrative templates** >> **System**

[image]

- Select and edit “**Specify Settings for optional component installation and component repair**”
- **Enable** and select “**Contract Windows Update directly to download repair content instead of Windows Server Update Services (WSUS)**”

[image]

- Re-run the prerequisite installation