# Share Point Installation Error :The tool was unable to install Application Server Role, Web Server (IIS) Role

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, administration, central-administration, farm-admin

- I had installed all the pre-requisites required for SharePoint 2013
  installation.But I come across to the error **The tool was unable to
  install Application Server Role, Web Server (IIS) Role.**
- Also I see all the features of Web Server in Active mode ,But I don't find any luck to move further.Can any one please help me in solving this issue

Comment: please check the post https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/142955/install-step-for-sharepoint-2013-fails-on-my-windows-server-2012-r2

Answer (score 0):

I guess the the installer is trying to run the executable C:\Windows\System32\ServerManagerCMD.exe

Taking a look in the system32 directory, you'll see that in R2, ServerManagerCMD.exe doesn't exist!
Source: 
[Server 2012 R2 and SharePoint 2013: The tool was unable to install Application Server Role, Web Server (IIS) Role](http://www.someshinyobject.com/posts/server-2012-r2-and-sharepoint-2013-the-tool-was-unable-to-install-application-server-role-web)

and microsoft has also provided a kb for this

[The Products Preparation Tool in SharePoint Server 2013 may not progress past "Configuring Application Server Role, Web Server (IIS) Role"](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2765260)